# Should I use requestAnimationFrame for updating attributes of HTML elements in high speed?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I know it's recommended to repaint `<canvas>` with `requestAnimationFrame` but I'm not sure if it's applied to attribute updating with high speed (every 20ms or `ontouchmove`) too?

Comment: Different HTML attributes trigger different types of actions, so there can't be a general rule here. Can you specify which attributes you're setting?

Comment: `style` and `value` attribute specifically in my case

Comment: As far as `style` is concerned, again, no general rule here. It depends on which CSS properties you're setting. Some properties cause page reflows, others don't. If the property you're setting causes a reflow, you certainly want to use requestAnimationFrame.